# How to set cookie in Jquery for JQM webApp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile, cookies

This must be very simple question .

I have a script to set cookie like this

```
<script>
$(document).on('pagecreate','#outerPage',function(e) {

   var windowWidth = $(this).width();
  // alert(windowWidth);
   if(windowWidth <290)
   {    
       console.log('cookie :small');
       $.cookie("adds", 0);
       //setTestCookie("adds","0");
   }
   else
   {   
         console.log('cookie :Big');
       $.cookie("adds", 1);

       //setTestCookie("adds","1");
   }
});
</script>
```

So if these cookies are set I am displaying or hiding a google add using php if() else statement simple as of now.

Till now I have been using this function called `setTestCookie()` but there was a problem that the if else statement was working on when I load the page two time . that means the cookies where  setting only after loading the page twice .

So I went to Jquery website and used this function `$.cookie()` to set the cookie but it result into loading page Image and the webpage never loads.

Any one has any idea why is this happening .

In short when I use `$.cookie()` the page loader Image shows but the page never loads .

**ERROR in Console**

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: @JayBlanchard `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function `  Its this

Comment: Did you include the cookie plugin code on your page?

Comment: oh no I did not I just used this Function

Comment: Using cookies in jQuery requires a plugin. https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: @JayBlanchard okay I used the plugin . And the cookie is working fine . But my adds  are not showing. Still

Comment: Check your `windowWidth` variable - it is probably not set.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I removed the cookie related code and tested looks like the problem is in the google adds . The thing is the mobile version of the add they load after the page loads twice but the other adds like the desktop version they are loading fine . I think some error in my page is not letting it load .